# Как сделать такую фичу в дизайне

Tags: javascript, html, css, design

На сайте Inbox Google [Вот](https://inbox.google.com/?pli=1) увидел интересную реализацию в дизайне. Функциональные кнопки появляются только при наведении на блок(перейдите и убедитесь сами). Не могу понять как это реализовано. Может где есть готовые примеры или какая реализация?

Comment: снизу справа???

Comment: нет. на письмо когда наводишь. Но ниже уже ответ дали

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы про кнопки, которые возникают при наведении на письмо, то делается это через селектор `:hover`родительского элемента.

```css
.outer {
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
}

.inner {
  display: none;   
}

.outer:hover .inner {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <button>Open</button>
    <button>Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: спасибо добрый человек